# ng grid: Is there a way to render two rows per record? (or HTML after row?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid, and I would like to have a second row that can be optionally displayed within an ng-grid, that contains a smaller grid/list of values pertaining to that row.

Here is a rough plunkr mockup of what I am going for:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6Wgpk7jxJLDY7wv023Ne?p=preview

Is there any way to accomplish this with ng-grid?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are just looking after the Master Detail: http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/#/masterdetail

Note that you don't need to show all your columns in the master grid.

So if your data looks like this:

```
[
  {name: "John Doe", street: "123 Main St.", phone: "(555)555-0199", purchases: [] },
  {name: "Jane Doe", street: "123 Main St.", phone: "(555)555-0198", purchases: [{item: "hat", price: "12"}, {item: "yellow shoes", price: "125"}]}
];
```

You can only show the first three in your grid:

```
 $scope.colDefs = [
    {field  : "name"},
    {field : "street"},
    {field  : "phone"}
    ];
```

and show the additional columns as soon as you have selected a row by adding this to the gridoptions

```
selectedItems: $scope.mySelections
```

Finally, to display the additional columns you can for instance use the ng-repeat directive

```
<div class="footer" ng-repeat="item in mySelections">
    <span class=header>Item</span>
    <span class=header>Price</span>
    <p ng-repeat="purchase in item.purchases">
          <span>{{purchase.item}}</span>
          <span>{{purchase.price}}</span>
    </p>
    </div>
```

I've worked it out in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/iGz1RjOILjP2VZxEt1ny